# jQuery click button don't work after applying filter in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

I have kendo grid that contain button in a column

first the click function work  but when i apply a filter or sortable in the grid  the click don't work any more

here's my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    // kindo grid initialization

    jQuery("#grid").kendoGrid({
        sortable : true,
        resizable : true,
        pageable : {
            pageSize : 7,
            messages : {
                display : "{0}-{1} de {2} demand",
                itemsPerPage : "demand by pages",
                empty : "There are no demand"
            }
        },
        filterable : {
            extra : false,
            messages : {
                filter : "apply",
                clear : "delete",
                info : "Filter :"
            },
            operators : {
                string : {
                    eq : "equal",
                    neq : "not equal",
                    contains : "contains"
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // the input type button that i want to get the click handler 
    // work fine but when i apply filter on the grid it doesn't work any more
    // css class of the input is viewIcon

    jQuery(".viewIcon").click(function(){

        var idDT = this.id;

            jQuery("#consultation").hide().load("../dt/consultation/view.jsp",{id:idDT},function( response, status, xhr ) {

                 // some work
            });

        });
});
</script>
</head>
<title>table</title>
<body >

<div id="bord">
    <table id="grid"  style="width: 98%">
        <colgroup>
            <col/><col style="width: 60px" /><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/>
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Numéro d'affaire</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Etat</th>
                <th>Demandeur</th>
                <th>Responsable projet</th>
                <th>Date de réception</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <%--  i get data from an sql query recordset  --%>

        <c:forEach var="dt_r" items="${recordset.rows}">
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center">${dt_r.n_aff_proj}</td>
                <td align="center">DT</td>
                <td align="center">${dt_r.etat_dem}</td>
                <td align="center">${dt_r.nom_dem}</td>
                <td align="center">${dt_r.resp_pro}</td>
                <fmt:formatDate var="fmt_date_reception_demande"
                    value="${dt_r.dat_r_d}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
                <td align="center">${fmt_date_reception_demande}</td>
                <td align="center">
                    <div class="actions">
                        <%--  the actions  --%>

                             <input type="button" title="Consulter DT" class="viewIcon" id="${dt_r.id_dt}" />

                    </div>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</div >

<div id="consultation">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

please  help

here is link on JSFiddle  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/waelkat/mds5t0au/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `.delegate()` for elements that you create dynamically.

> .delegate() Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements
>   that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set
>   of root elements. [more](http://jqapi.com/#p=delegate)

```
jQuery('#bord').on('click', '.viewIcon', function() {
    alert("yess");          
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shiralizadeh/mds5t0au/3/)

Comment: a have another bug now the filter work fine at first and the action button work after applying filter . but when i click in the viewIcon button the filter donc work the pop up dosen't show any more any idea please

Comment: when i click on button then i try to filter  the popup filter dont work any more and i have this error message from fireBug 

""TypeError: this.popup is undefined
 

...n(),this.popup||this.pane||this._init(),this._isMobile?this.pane.navigate(this.v... """
i think the probleme from  var idDT = this.id; from click function 
look at the code in stack overflow please 
any helps please

Comment: can i get the id of the clicked button without using this.id
i try to remove it and it work
is there other methode to get the id other than this.id

Comment: using jQuery: `$(this).attr('id')` or `$(this).prop('id')`

Comment: thanx again and again mohamed u really saved my day